# AngularJS: Component won't show data loaded via HTTP

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to achieve something like: send a HTTP request in my component, then get the data, and finally I can display these data in my component. Although I can get data through HTTP request, I can't display them in my component now. What's wrong with my code and what should I do?

here is my component html:

```
<div class="box box-solid">
<div class="box-header">
    <div class="app-info-wrapper">
        <img class="info-pic" src="" alt="ss">
        <div class="app-info">
            <p>name: {{$ctrl.app.name}}</p>
            <p>create at：{{$ctrl.app.createTime}}</p>
            <p>creator：{{$ctrl.app.creator}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box-body">
    The body of the box
</div>
```

and this is my component js:

```
angular.module('myApp').component('appInfo',{
    templateUrl: 'component/app-info/app-info.html',
    controller: ['$http','$log',function appInfoCtrl($http,$log){
        $http({
            url: "/api/app/1",
            method: "get"
        }).then(function (response) {
            this.app = response.data;
        });
    }]
});
```

response.data:

```
{"id":1,"name":"test demo","createTime":"2018-01-01 00:09:02","creator":"cr"}
```

Comment: post your whole template

Comment: use {{app.name}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is this line:

```
this.app = response.data;
```

`this` here doesn't point to the controller. It points to the context of the anonymous function instead. To correct this, you can save the reference of controller's context in a variable and use it like this:

```
controller: ['$http','$log',function appInfoCtrl($http,$log){
    var vm = this;

    $http({
        url: "/api/app/1",
        method: "get"
    }).then(function (response) {
        vm.app = response.data;
    });
}]
```

Alternatively, you can use the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to skip using `vm` at all, like this:

```
controller: ['$http','$log',function appInfoCtrl($http,$log){
    $http({
        url: "/api/app/1",
        method: "get"
    }).then(response => {
        this.app = response.data;
    });
}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I'll accept your answer sooner.